# Problem with Do

Tags: list-manipulation

Good day, I want to assign some values in a list as in the following way:

[image]

The problem is that when I run the program, it does not assign any value to alpha. Does anyone know why?
Thanks for your help

Comment: To assign values, one need to use `Set (=)`; `Equal (==)` is to compare values or to establish equations.

Comment: Do you want `Table`?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the problem @Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ noted, your `Do` repeatedly redefines alpha, rather than making a list. I imagine what you want is not a `Do` loop at all, but:

```
alpha=states[[All,1]]
```

`Do` loops are rarely the best tool for the job in *Mathematica*.